# Why can I not see the VS 2005 dataset visualizer anymore?

Tags: visual-studio-2005, dataset, visualizer

I cannot see the magnifying glass next to my `Dataset` anymore. Is there a way to re-enable it?

Comment: I asked a similar question, but haven't gotten an answer yet..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio/694565#694565

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and found a solution: [solution to disappearing dataset visualizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio/1978806#1978806)