# Visual Studio 2008 Exception Window replaced by a Pop-up Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, exception

Greetings,

I have this annoying problem where my exception window in Visual Studio 2008 is replaced by a Windows pop-up dialog box (see images below).  The exception detail can be quite usefull, so any help would be appreciated.

[Visual Studio 2008 - Exception Window #1 http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/692/window.png](http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/692/window.png)

[Windows Dialog - Exception Window #2 http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/8379/window2.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/8379/window2.png)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. As with Sephrial my "Enable the Exception Assistant"-Option is enabled.
Any other news here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question [#239206](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio) did help me.
Running

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /resetskippkgs
```

on the Commandline (as Administrator) did the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the Exception Assistant is still enabled.

- GoTo: Tools -> Options -> Debugging
- Ensure "Enable the Exception Assistant" is checked

Comment: Thanks JaredPar, believe it or not I had "Enable the exception assistant" checked.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this happening when I enable unmanaged code debugging in the project properties.

Comment: So, I assume disabling unmanaged code debugging then fixes the problem?

Comment: It fixed it for me, but since Nils fixed the problem without touching the project properties I'm guessing there are multiple causes for the problem.