# Displaying 2D array in visual studio debugger

Tags: visual-studio, immediate-window

I am working with Visual Studio 2005 and have a 2D array (say my2Dvar) that I would like to see the values of during run time. I am looking to export these values into Matlab. I tried displaying the values using `?my2DVar` in the immediate window. But the values aren't displayed properly (the elements of the array show up as {...}). I can hover the mouse over the variable and expand the small plus signs that appears to look at the individual entries but the array is too big for me to do this for all entries.

Question: Is there a way to export the values of the 2D-array to a file from which it can be easily read by other platforms? I would appreciate any help. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Visual Studio's default data visualizers aren't handling your custom data types, you can [write your own visualizers for Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the data visualizer doesn't seem to be working in my machine. I don't see the magnifying glass symbol next to any of my variables. Others seem to have run into a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio/694565#694565). Is there another way to do this? My arrays aren't even fancy data types - just plain 2-D array of floating point numbers.

Comment: VS should be able to display a plain 2D array of floats, if it is declared as an actual float[x,y] array.  That you're not seeing any visualizers at all in VS sounds very ominous.  Something is broken in your VS installation.  You might want to try to fix that first.