# Visual Studio: Dataset and DataTable Visualizer not working in watch window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2005, watch, visualizer

I have just installed visual studio 2005 service pack 1 on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.  Everything appears to work fine and I am able to run my project without any errors.  However, when I am in debug mode I have noticed a problem with the "Watch" window for DataTables and DataSets.

I have a DataTable named dt and I enter it in the watch window. No magnifying glass appears to open the visualizer and I get the following error in the value column:

```
0x000000001d438c90 { KEY_XMLSCHEMA="XmlSchema" KEY_XMLDIFFGRAM="XmlDiffGram" KEY_NAME="TableName" ...}
```

Has anyone else had this problem? I have tried everything in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio/1978806#1978806) and searched all around google but nothing worked.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't award a bounty to yourself. It's just the way the system was designed. See this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105033/when-can-i-not-give-a-bounty-to-myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to copy all the files in C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Visualizers to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers.  Specifically it was missing autoexp.dll and autoexpce.dll.