# Visual Studio 2015 DataTable/DataSet Visualizer crashes IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visualizer, debuggervisualizer

Whenever I try to open the DataTable or DataSet Visualizer it crashes the IDE.

I tried the various command-line switches to reset everything, started in /SafeMode and undertook a repair of VS. 
Nothing has helped so far.

As far as I can tell it's only those two visualizers that crash.

I also tried starting VS with the /Log switch, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to log the crash there...

How can I find out what's the problem and fix it?

EDIT:

Seems like a problem with the .NET Framework prior to version 4.0:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1711642
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1709336

Comment: capture a dump (technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx, msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787181%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the crashing setup app. Open the crash dump in windbg, fix the debug symbols (stackoverflow.com/a/30019890/1466046), run **!analyze -v** and post the output.

Comment: The above didn't fix it for me, but this link did:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408234/visual-studio-dataset-and-datatable-visualizer-not-working-in-watch-window/8448629#8448629

Comment: Hallelujah! Update 1 fixes this!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem after 4h experimenting I manage to fix it by going to

***Tools => Options => Debugging*** and turning on ***Use Managed Compatibility Mode***

Found better workaround 
***Tools => Options => Debugging*** and turning on ***Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators*** 
This one doesn't turn off some new features like "Diagnostic Tools".

Update - **Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 Fixes this problem**

Comment: Thank you very much! This workaround appears to do the work! Accepted as answer since Microsoft acknowledged the bug and are working to fix it, but this setting circumvents it.

Comment: This is a good workaround. Shame MS is too lazy to fix anything quickly.

Comment: I have recieved an email stating that this has been fixed in next update. They wont divulge a date to though.

Comment: Your _4h experimenting_ save us a lot of suffering and pain

Answer (score 0):

External debugger visualizers are currently broken in Visual Studio 2015. This includes the DataSetVisualizer and the WpfTreeVisualizer.

Answer (score -3):

Go to `Tools > Options > Debugging` and turn on `Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators`

Comment: This solution was already added to the accepted answer yesterday. Why do you feel the need to repeat the accepted answer?