# DataTable visualizer nowhere to be found in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This is driving me crazy. When I'm debugging, I don't have the magnifying glass icon to see the data inside my DataTable. I tried [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2009/11/24/wheres-my-good-old-friend-dataset-visualizer/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408234/visual-studio-dataset-and-datatable-visualizer-not-working-in-watch-window/8448629#8448629) solution to no avail.

How in the world I get the icon back??

Thank you!

Comment: This appears to be a .NET Core specific issue and Microsoft is planning this feature for a future release of VS. 

[link to reference](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/99999/dataset-visualizer-missing-for-net-core-20.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but posting my fix since it was very frustrating as I wasted a few hours trying to troubleshoot the issue.

It turned out to be my project type. I created a new .NET framework (non-core) project and it magically reappeared.

Apparently it is a known issue with .NET Core.