# Visual Studio 2019 Datatable visualizer missing

Tags: c#, user-interface, datatable, visual-studio-2019, visualizer

I download VS2019 yesterday and so far it was pretty nice so far. Testing out some projects I found out that the visualizer for the datatables is totally missing, I do some google research for that but nothing come out.

[image: Where is the visualizer?]

There it's suppose to be the visualizer but nothing show up.

**EDIT**

I'm using .NetFramework 4.5

There is not like a "sample code" because i can't visualize anywhere, in every line of code where I use a Datatable I'm not able to see it.

Comment: Is it .net core or .net framework? put some sample code so anyone can try to reproduce

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Visual+Studio+2019+Datatable+visualizer+missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my question with what work for me, thanks to the reply from [zzz...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711718/zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz) in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8448629/8027036). I check the follow folder:

***C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2019***

and I notice that the **Visualizers** folder is missing, I just copy the **Visualizers** folder from

***C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015***

to the 2019 folder and that was all. I think this bad-instalation happends when you install Visual Studio in a disk that isn't the system default, but this is just a theory.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your issue was successfully resolved. You can mark your reply as the answer so that others can solve the similar problem.