# IEnumerable Visualizer option is missing

Tags: ienumerable, visual-studio-2022, debuggervisualizer

I'm using the latest version of VS 2022 (Version 17.2.6).
When I create a new (console) application I am able to use the IEnumerable Visualizer.
[Visualizer at work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGaGT.png)

But when I paste this same, simple code into my existing code the option to view the IEnumerable Visualizer is missing.
[Visualizer option (View) is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0luXQ.png)

I have no clue why this doesn't work in my code, other that it may have something to do with the .Net version of the projects. The first one is .Net 6, the second one is .Net 5.
But, as I understand, that shouldn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

Thnx in advance
Henk

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61261826/6530134 Maybe try and delete your Visualizer folder if its present, and try again?