# Visual Studio Debug Visualizer not working for Datatable (Unhandled exception has occurred in a component in your application)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, visualizer, debuggervisualizer

> **Unhandled exception has occurred in a component in your application.**

**When I click the the magnifier button in debug model, the debug visualizer doesn't work only for datatable, while working for other types like string.**

[image: Debug Visualizer works for String]

[image: Debug Visualizer not working for Datatable]

[image: debuggervisualizer.dll]

**I have searched old posts and cannot find a useful answer.
This is the detail of exception:**

> See the end of this message for details on invoking  just-in-time
>   (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
>
> ************** Exception Text ************** System.Exception: Function evaluation timed out.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.PrivateCallback.MaybeDeserializeAndThrowException(Byte[]
>   data)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.DebugViewerShim.ManagedShim.DelegatedHost.CreateViewer(IntPtr
>   hwnd, HostServicesHelper hsh, SafeProxyWrapper proxy)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager
>       Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager/v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.AppDomainManager.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34238 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Configuration
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.18408 built by: FX451RTMGREL
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Xml
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34234 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34251 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
>       Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34270 built by: FX452RTMGDR
>       CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
>   ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers
>       Assembly Version: 10.0.0.0
>       Win32 Version: 10.0.30319.1
>
> ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers/10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll
>
> ************** JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
>   (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
>   system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
>   with debugging enabled.
>
> For example:
>
> When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to
>   the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by
>   this dialog box.

Comment: How much data are you expecting in the datatable? Have you tried replicating the issue with a small datatable?

Comment: may be this will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239206/datatable-visualizer-disappeared-from-my-visual-studio

Comment: The datatable is very small, not containing much data.

Answer (score -1):

Try,
Execute devenv.exe and run as admin, this solve your problem easly.